Import errors while running airflow on ec2
I am trying to run aiflow on ec2 machine.I am running the webserver in one terminal and scheduler in the other terminal.While running both of these in foreground, there are no import errors.And when I run these in deamon mode using the '-D' flag these throw import errors.
I am deploying the pipeline on ec2 to run in deamon mode.I have some user defined module from which I am importing it in my tasks.(i.e a yaml file).Hence when I am reading this file to get variables in the code and running this in foreground, I have no import erros and running it in deamon mode throws import errors like this.
In this while running it in foreground gives no import errors.
Here is a code snippet for the same.
I have an dag divided into 3 tasks as per ETL.The defination for each are python callable that is stored in a another file as a module that will be imported.
The gist of the task is given here.
(Python file etl.py)
import yaml

with open("_credentials/global_config.yml", "r") as filename:
        global_config = yaml.load(filename, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

def extract_data():
    #  YAML contains API credentials under 'api_key'
    api_key = global_config.get('api_key')
    
    # Further using api_key to call API

def transform_data(raw_data):
    pass

def load_data(transformed_data):
    pass


Also this is my folder sturcture:
airflow_pipelines
    |-- airflow/
            |-- _credentials/
                     global_config.yml
            |-- tasks/
                |-- etl.py
            |-- dags/
                |-- group_of_dags_1/
                |-- group_of_dags_2/



Can any one help me out with this issue and help me identify what am I missing out?

does the file or directory in the error message that was posted exist ?

Yes, the directory and file both exists.As I said it is running correctly in foreground but throws import errors while in deamon mode.

okay,  show the code that does the import...

@D.L I have update the question for better understanding.

looks like this is to do with file path between what is described as the "foreground" and the "daemon"...

Can you give a detailed view of why this might be happening and what can I do to resolve this.

the best way to resolve is to use the full file path instead of a relative path. This way it them becomes unambiguous where the file is.

Why does airflow not parse the files correctly when running in daemon  mode, while it parses correctly in foreground?
